# 2 spaces in a PDF file are rendered as a single space

Tags: pdf, itext

I created a PDF file that has multiple spaces between characters. It is that way in the PDF. But when rendered by Acrobat, it's a single space between each word. This is causing a problem with a barcode font.

PDF:

```
0 0 0 rg
(Before  after  two  spaces.)Tj
```

Any ideas why? (the PDF is at http://simba.windward.net/temp/PdfSpacing.pdf)

Comment: Using iText. Is there some kind of global setting needed to tell Acrobat don't combine spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, there are TWO spaces exactly.

[image]

This is one space for your case (font, size, etc.)

[image]

The space glyph is not the 'W' letter size. It depends of designer point of view. If it absolutely necessary for you to SET the width of space as some real BIG value, you can do it in the font descriptor section as width of space character exactly.

Thank You.

Comment: Do a copy from Acrobat and a paste then to Word. It's one space. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Mac user. I have not the Acrobat and the MSWord applications. But it is OK. I trust you, what copy/paste can transform the text. It is the Windows clipboard funny behavior. May be the developers of the Windows clipboard/word transition calls it "optimization")) For example, when I copied the text from your PDF in Chrome, Safari and Preview (native Mac applications for PDF view) and paste it in TextMate or TextEdit – I can see exactly two spaces.

Comment: Can you copy/paste to the Notepad?

Comment: Thank you - yes that appears to be it. And it does render correctly with the barcode font, just doesn't copy right.

Comment: I just want to know, you are copying BARCODE as the TEXT content from the PDF file to the WORD? I mean, why it necessary to do that way? I know, how the font works, and I am not sure, what this way is really worth the time you waste for it. If you are "itext" user (pdf generator app), the better way to do the barcode job is localize the barcode generator in the external php image processor, like number->php image generator->barcode->imported image. Copy/paste of image will never change content of the barcode. Thank You!

Comment: David, I have an idea. If it is absolutely necessary to do copy/paste without loosing double space, can you change encoding for space symbol in font descriptor? For example, you can use dot or underscore as a space glyph.

Comment: The reason you want to use a font is so you can easily size/format the bar code and have it be an inline part of the text it is with. And it also give you the ability to copy/paste (the reason both spaces are needed) so you can copy from one report and paste in another.

Comment: Look at this: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1YEM-11PerqX2RsVlA4SFI0TW8/edit I mean, you can avoid spaces AS IS by creating differences. It is just an idea. I have not tested it yet on a Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

Your document contains 2 spaces between each word. Foxit, SumatraPDF and other PDF viewers extract the text with 2 spaces. Only Acrobat seems to perform some kind of "optimization" and merge the spaces when selecting and copying text. 
When displaying the file the space between words corresponds to 2 spaces also in Acrobat, the problem appears only for copy/paste operations. This behavior in Acrobat cannot be disabled.
In what way does this affect your barcode text?